# Laravel comparing Query result with variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these two variables

```
$categories = Relation::select('child_id', 'distance')
->where('parent_id', $request->who)
->orderBy('distance', 'asc')
->get();

$request->newParent;
```

*Is there any way to check if my query `result($categories)` contains id same as `$request->newParent` without making another database query.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$categories = Relation::with('newParent')
 ->select('parent_id','child_id', 'distance')->where('parent_id', 
$request->newParent)->orderBy('distance', 'asc')->get();

return $categories;
```